# What is the best option for mutable NFTs (ERC721 or ERC1155)?

Tags: nft, erc-721, polygon, erc-1155, meta-data

I am researching on the best option to have mutable metadata for NFTs (`ERC721` and `ERC1155`).

What is the best option? Is anybody already using any approach to this?

[Tableland](https://docs.tableland.xyz/) has just come to my attention. Is it worth using this solution to update the metadata of my NFTs? Are there more options out there?

Answer (score 1):

About the first question, it does depend. If you want to change the metadata of just one NFT you need to use ERC721, if you will have some copies of a NFT that will change at the same time ERC1155 it's referred.

About Tableland, you need to think about what solution you prefer to manage your metadata, it will change a lot depending on the use case! Most of the times, maybe you could make it work with your own backend and with AWS S3.

Comment: Can you please share more information on how to achieve this using a backend and AWS S3?